# pandas conditional selection - returning a view not a copy

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have an original pandas Dataframe with a chain of objects doing conditional selection on it. Each time I do a conditional selection, pandas creates a new dataframe. In other words:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=range(3,23), B=range(5,25)))
print(id(df))

df2 = df[df['A']> 15]
print(id(df2))


df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=range(3,43), B=range(5,45)))
print(id(df))

# output: 
139963862409288
139963862409456
139963862275296
```

In the above example, I want `df2` to change when I update `df`. I know that now because I rebind the variable df to a new Pandas DataFrame (a new object), its ID changes and `df2` is not connected to the new `df` anymore. Is there anyway to do it the way I want? Is there any method/attribute in pandas to keep the connection between the original Dataframe and my conditional selection, or any Pythonic way I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 1):

What are you trying to accomplish? Maybe it can be accomplished in a different way?

Regarding having views instead of copies -- when you select a single row or column, you have a view. The code below demonstrates this:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(A=range(8,13), B=range(10,15), C=range(-3,2)))
print(df)
print('-----------')

dfa = df['A']
df2 = df.loc[2]
dfi = df.iloc[2]

dfa[2]=42
df2['B']=99
dfi['C']=-1
print(df)
print(dfa)
print(df2)
print(dfi)
```